# Hive - set partitioning of external table based on file path

Tags: hive, hdfs, datetime-format, hiveql

I have a job that is writing files to hdfs accorring to the following format:

```
/table_name/yyyy/MM/dd/HH/mm/ss/file_name.avro
```

Is it possible to define Hive external table that is being partitioned by both year and timestamp (HH:mm:ss) without moving files and renaming the directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this by writing load data statements for each yyyy/HH/mm/ss instance.

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/table_name/yyyy/MM/dd/HH/mm/ss/file_name.avro' INTO TABLE tablename PARTITION (year=yyyy, hour=HH, minute=mm, second=ss)
```

Comment: Can I somehow concatenate hour, minute and second into single column?

Comment: If you define partition column as type of string, of course,.

Comment: In case of concatenation, you should use partition filter with like using % when you want to wildcard search for example on second field. E.g select * from tablename where my_part like 'HH_mm_%'. Additionally, dropping might be an issue. You cannot write such a statement: drop partition (my_part like 'HH_mm_%'). You should write drop partition (my_part='HH_mm_ss') for each second.

Comment: cool, it works. One more question though - some of this paths may be updated (another avro file may arrive for the same hh:mm:ss) is there a generic way to add new files afterwards (like with msck repair table) and avoid loading the same data twice?

Comment: Use this to add a directory as partition: `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PARTITION partition(tstamp='yyyy_hh_mm_ss') LOCATION '/table_name/yyyy/MM/dd/HH/mm/ss'`